# Installing Stata16 on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, shared-library

Hey I am new to Ubuntu and just trying to install Stata16. I downloaded it and ran the installation according to https://acarril.github.io/posts/install-stata-linux
, including verification of serial number etc. After that I am asked to run

```
./stata
```

or

```
./xstata
```

But both give me the error

> error while loading shared libraries: libpng16.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have also tried stata-mp, stata-se, and xstata-mp, xstata-se.
Can anyone help? As I said I am new to Ubuntu, so without very clear instructions I am quite lost.

Comment: Have you tried adding `libpng16-16`  (https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libpng16-16) , ie. `sudo apt-get install libpng16-16`   (It's found in 'universe' repository, so if you haven't already enabled 'universe' you'll need to enable it) https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: fyi:  on my last comment, if you like using a browser, remembering `packages.ubuntu.com` is really handy, if not `apt-cache search libpng` would have given you the results from a terminal even faster.  *ps:  I've never heard of Stata16, so my suggestion is guess - but hopefully useful even if not the answer you need*